# How to count processes in BASH, including those JUST started?

Tags: bash, process, sleep, ps

I need to run various jobs in background using /Cobra.

I have 32 cores and I want to keep couple free otherwise my machine get too slow to do other things.

In this code I check the number of processes using ps and only start up to max number of 30.

However, "ps" does not appear to give information in a timely fashion. Even though I wait 3 seconds, ps sometimes under declares the number of matching processes. This is presumably when they are just getting started in background.

Is there anyway to get a better answer from ps (or otehrwise), the only solution I have is to sleep for longer, but that is a bit heavy-handed.

```
#!/bin/sh
#set -x

while true
do
    NUMRUNNING=`ps | egrep FormsApplic | wc -l` 

    JOBS=`cat jobs.lst | wc -l`
    if [ $JOBS -gt 0 ]
    then

        MAXSTART=$((30-$NUMRUNNING))
        NUMTOSTART=$JOBS

        if [ $NUMTOSTART -gt $MAXSTART ]
        then
            NUMTOSTART=$MAXSTART
        fi 
        for ((i=1;i<=$NUMTOSTART;i++))
        do
            JOB=`head -n1 jobs.lst`
            echo $JOB >> /tmp/jobsStarted
            sed -i 1d jobs.lst
            /cobra $JOB &

        done

    fi

    LASTNUMRUNNING=$NUMRUNNING
    sleep 3
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`ps` should list the processes immediately. I'm not sure what's going wrong for you but this script has a few improvements. Chief among these is using `pgrep` instead of parsing `ps`. Let me know if it solves your issue:

```
while true
do
    NUMRUNNING=$(pgrep -c FormsApplic)

    JOBS=$(wc -l jobs.lst)
    if [ "$JOBS" -gt 0 ]
    then

        MAXSTART=$((30-$NUMRUNNING))
        NUMTOSTART=$JOBS

        if [ "$NUMTOSTART" -gt "$MAXSTART" ]
        then
            NUMTOSTART="$MAXSTART"
        fi 
        for ((i=1;i<="$NUMTOSTART";i++))
        do
            JOB=$(head -n1 jobs.lst)
            echo "$JOB" >> /tmp/jobsStarted
            sed -i 1d jobs.lst
            /cobra "$JOB" &
        done

    fi

    LASTNUMRUNNING=$NUMRUNNING
    sleep 3
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /proc pseudo-file-system:

CURRENTLY_RUNNING=$(find /proc/[0-9]*/exe 2>/dev/null |grep cobra |wc -l)

Another way would be to create a PID file each time you start /cobra and just count the files. The only problem then is to delete the PID-File. This can be archived by a wrapper-script:

/cobra.sh:

```
touch /var/run/cobra/run.$$
/cobra
rm /var/run/cobra/run.$$
```

Comment: Not all operating systems have a `/proc` filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than querying the number of processes, maintain a counter yourself.

```
num_running=0
while read job; do
    if [ $num_running -eq $max_start ]; then
        # wait for the oldest job to complete. Not ideal,
        # since another job might complete before that one.
        wait $(jobs -p | head -n 1)
        num_running=$((num_running  - 1))
    fi
    /cobra $JOB &
    num_running=$((num_running+1))
done < jobs.lst
```

If you are using `bash` 4.3, you can (finally!) wait on an arbitrary job to complete, rather than a specific subset of all jobs.

```
num_running=0
while read job; do
    if [ $num_running -eq $max_start ]; then
        # Wait for any one background job to complete
        wait -n
        num_running=$((num_running  - 1))
    fi
    /cobra $JOB &
    num_running=$((num_running+1))
done < jobs.lst
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try replacing your entire script by this line:

```
< jobs.lst xargs -n 1 -P 30 /cobra
```

The `xargs` command will dispath each line of `jobs.lst` as argument to the `/cobra` command, creating 30 parallel processes at maximum.

Here is a synthetic example:

```
$ cat jobs.lst 
1
2
3
4

$ time < jobs.lst xargs -n 1 -P 2 sleep & 
[1] 5291
$ ps aux|grep -i [s]leep|grep -v xargs
user       5297   0.0  0.0  2426644    320 s002  S     3:25PM   0:00.00 sleep 2
user       5296   0.0  0.0  2426644    320 s002  S     3:25PM   0:00.00 sleep 1
$ ps aux|grep -i [s]leep|grep -v xargs
user       5297   0.0  0.0  2426644    320 s002  S     3:25PM   0:00.00 sleep 2
user       5303   0.0  0.0  2426644    320 s002  S     3:25PM   0:00.00 sleep 3
$ ps aux|grep -i [s]leep|grep -v xargs
user       5309   0.0  0.0  2426644    320 s002  S     3:25PM   0:00.00 sleep 4
user       5303   0.0  0.0  2426644    320 s002  S     3:25PM   0:00.00 sleep 3
$ ps aux|grep -i [s]leep|grep -v xargs
user       5309   0.0  0.0  2426644    320 s002  S     3:25PM   0:00.00 sleep 4
$ 
real    0m6.014s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.009s
```

And you can see that 2 jobs are running in parallel at each moment, for a total running time of 2+4=6 seconds.